# include php file with several js files

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a small problem. I uploaded 3 files to my server. 1 php file and 2 js files. PHP file have reference to this 2 JS files. I need to run this files on my page in wordpress. I tried to install EXEC PHP plugin, and i wrote

```
include './online/demo_iframe.php';
wp_enqueue_script( "jquery.ba-postmessage", "./online/jquery.ba-postmessage.js", false, false ); 
wp_enqueue_script( "jquery.min", "./online/jquery.min.js", false, false );
```

but this not working. So, the question, that i know how to run php file, with "include" but i dont know how to connect this php file with my 2 js files. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears URL path problem, try to use the full (not relative) path to your files:

```
<?php
//For PHP include, use full path to your file, e.g. /var/www/example.com/wp-content/themes/etc/etc
include 'full_path_to_your_php_file/online/demo_iframe.php';
//For JS scripts, use bloginfo('url') to point to your files
wp_enqueue_script( "jquery.ba-postmessage", bloginfo('url')."/path_to_your_theme_file/online/jquery.ba-postmessage.js", false, false ); 
wp_enqueue_script( "jquery.min", bloginfo('url')."/path_to_your_theme_file/online/jquery.min.js", false, false );
```

Comment: Not working yet..But it is possible, to make a web address for wordpress page like this www.mysite/cataloge/demo_iframe.php ? But this address must also read 2 JS files, from the same cataloge ?